# How to separate command switches (/x) from arguments in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, command-line-arguments

I know in linux, I can just write `command -a -b - "arg1" "arg2"...`, where single hyphen is "option/switch" separator. But how can I do similar in windows cmd?

I would like to see only particular option/switch from help:
`c:\> setx /? | findstr /r '/m'`, where the `/m` switch I want to find. but the `findstr` uses it as another switch:

`FINDSTR: Bad command line`.

How to achieve that?

Comment: @FrankThomas `setx /? | findstr /r '\/M'` does not work (it is the wrong kind of quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want to find the `/m` switch

> I'm using:
>
> ```
> setx /? | findstr /r '/m'
> ```

1. You do not need the `/r` switch (which specifies a regular expression) as `'/m'` is
   **not** a regular expression.
2. You are using the wrong kind of quotes (single `'` instead of `"`), it should be `"/m"`
3. `setx /?` outputs `/M` so you either need to use `/I` (ignore case) or `"/M"`
4. The `/` in `"/m"` needs to be escaped (using `\`), ie `"\/m"`, if you are not using the `/C:` (Use string as a literal search string) option

The following commands all do what you want:

```
setx /? | findstr "\/M"
setx /? | findstr /c:"/M"
setx /? | findstr /i "\/m"
setx /? | findstr /i /c:"/m"
```

Example output:

```
F:\test>setx /? | findstr "\/M"
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]] var value [/M]
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]] var /K regpath [/M]
         /F file {var {/A x,y | /R x,y string}[/M] | /X} [/D delimiters]
    /M                     Specifies that the variable should be set in
    SETX MACHINE "COMPAQ COMPUTER" /M
         NT\CurrentVersion\CurrentBuildNumber" /M
         CurrentVersion\CurrentBuildNumber" /M

F:\test>setx /? | findstr /c:"/M"
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]] var value [/M]
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]] var /K regpath [/M]
         /F file {var {/A x,y | /R x,y string}[/M] | /X} [/D delimiters]
    /M                     Specifies that the variable should be set in
    SETX MACHINE "COMPAQ COMPUTER" /M
         NT\CurrentVersion\CurrentBuildNumber" /M
         CurrentVersion\CurrentBuildNumber" /M

F:\test>setx /? | findstr /i "\/m"
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]] var value [/M]
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]] var /K regpath [/M]
         /F file {var {/A x,y | /R x,y string}[/M] | /X} [/D delimiters]
    /M                     Specifies that the variable should be set in
    SETX MACHINE "COMPAQ COMPUTER" /M
         NT\CurrentVersion\CurrentBuildNumber" /M
         CurrentVersion\CurrentBuildNumber" /M

F:\test>setx /? | findstr /i /c:"/m"
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]] var value [/M]
    SETX [/S system [/U [domain\]user [/P [password]]]] var /K regpath [/M]
         /F file {var {/A x,y | /R x,y string}[/M] | /X} [/D delimiters]
    /M                     Specifies that the variable should be set in
    SETX MACHINE "COMPAQ COMPUTER" /M
         NT\CurrentVersion\CurrentBuildNumber" /M
         CurrentVersion\CurrentBuildNumber" /M

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Findstr - Search for strings - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [Quotes, Escape Characters, Delimiters - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)